# ¿cómo consumir un servicio REST desde php?

Tags: php, webservice, rest

buenas tardes, intento conectarme a un REST pero obtengo el siguiente error

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://....): failed to open stream: HTTP
>   request failed!

No se mucho de PHP, asi que espero me puedan colaborar.

la url existe y funciona...asi que el problema esta en la manera como ingreso.
Este es el código que estoy usando:

Funcion envía correos cuando se crea un nuevo ticket.

```
 static function sendNotification($ticketID, $ticketTitle , $ticketMessage , $ticketPriority, $ticketCreationDate, $TicketDeadline, $TicketResponsible) {

        // Your token
        $postmanToken = 'abc123';

        // The data to send to the API
        $postData = array(
            'dato1' => $valor1,
            'dato2' => $valor2,
            'dato3' => $valor3
        );

        $options = array('http' => array(

            'async' => true,
            'crossDomain' => true,
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => 'content-type: application/json\r\n'.
                        'cache-control: no-cache"\r\n'.
                        'postman-token: '.$postmanToken.'\n',
            'processData' => false,
            'data' => json_encode($postData, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
        ));

        // Create the context for the request
        $context = stream_context_create($options);

        // Send the request
        $response = file_get_contents('https://....', false, $context, -1, 40000);

        // Check for errors
        if($response === FALSE){
            die('Error');
        }

        // Decode the response
        $responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);

        // Print the date from the response
        echo $responseData['published'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno al final lo hice por jquery y me funcionó, les comparto el código que utilicé:

```
        <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
                 var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({
                   "Campo1": "valor1",
                   "Campo2": "valor2",
                   "Campo3": "valor3",
                   ...
                 }));


                 var settings = {
                     "method": "POST",
                     "url": "https://....",
                     "data": data
                 }
             });
        </script>
```

y luego utilizo ajax para enviar los datos:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

me funciona de la manera que necesito, así que dejo cerrado el tema

Comment: Pero en esta respuesta no estas enviando ningún `header` especial, ademas, estas haciendo `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(`, que es lo mismo que no hacerlo... si esto asi te anduvo, entonces el `endpoint` seguramente no soporta un `body` en tipo `JSON` sino mas bien `urlencoded`.

Comment: asi es, cuando enviaba el header me salia un error, y decidi omitir el header y me funciona sin ningun problema cuando uso solo el JSON.stringify me genera el json pero el endpoint me lo reconoce como un text y me lo muestra vacio, cuando agrego el JSON.parse funciona

Comment: entiendo que ya has encontrado una solución, pero tu respuesta usa `JS`, cuando específicamente en tu pregunta has indicado que quieres hacerlo en `PHP`. Si aún estas interesado en hacerlo con `PHP`, avisame lo que he puesto te ha servido.

Comment: voy a tratar de hacerlo en php como dices, sino pues continuare con la opcion de jQuery

Comment: Con relacion al JSON.parser(JSON.stringify(data))).
La funcion JSON.stringify convierte un JSON en string.
JSON.parser convierte un string a JSON si esposible sintacticamente asi q como digo @Marcos al usar JSON.parser(JSON.stringify(data))) no estas haciendo nada, pueden mandarlo sin las dos funciones asi:

var data = {
           "Campo1": "valor1",
           "Campo2": "valor2",
           "Campo3": "valor3",
           ...
     };

Comment: y si lo reconoceria como se necesita? el endpoint necesita un json

Answer (score 0):

En tu código has agregado al [contexto opciones](http://php.net/manual/es/context.http.php) que no existen (*¿me suenan son de JS?*) y lo que esta mal, es como estas enviando los datos (*eg: content*)

Intenta hacerlo así:

```
// Armamos el string de parámetros a enviar
$postData = http_build_query(array(
    'dato1' => $valor1,
    'dato2' => $valor2,
    'dato3' => $valor3
));

$options = array('http' => array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $postData
));

// Creamos el contexto
$context = stream_context_create($options);

// Enviamos la solicitud
$response = file_get_contents('https://....', false, $context);
```

Comment: hice como dijiste y sigue saliendo el error en la misma linea:
file_get_contents('https://......', false, $context);

Comment: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Comment: la url no tiene parametros